# From transform to PMF?

Tags: probability

Here is a passage from Drake's applied probability book:

Let $p_x$ be the Probability Mass Function of a random variable $x$, we define the z-transform of $p_x$ as $p_x^T(z)$:
$$
p_x^T(z)  = p_x(0) + zp_x(1) + z^2p_x(2) + \cdots
$$
then is it possible to determine the individual terms of the PMF from $p_x^T(z)$ by the following formula? If yes, why?
$$
p_x(x_0) =
\frac{1}{x_0 !}
\left[
\frac{d^{x_0}}{dz^{x_0}}
p_x^T(z)
\right]_{z=0}
$$

For instance,
$$
p_x(3) =
\frac{1}{3 !}
\left[
\frac{d^3}{dz^3}
p_x^T(z)
\right]_{z=0}
$$

Comment: Your question is not self contained. At present one cannot know what you are asking. Please include all relevant information.

Comment: Oh, sorry, there was a typo, and it's now corrected. Also, the question has now become clear to me in the process of editing it. Thanks!